# Oracle - Converting a UTC timestamp to a localtime (GMT/BST) timestamp

Tags: oracle, datetime, utc

I have to create convert a datetime as UTC into localtime (GMT/BST)

The dates in the database are UTC AND the database is set to UTC.

I believe I can get the offset between UTC and (say) BST using TZ_OFFSET, but how can I then use that to convert the UTC datetime into a BST datetime?

So, for example, if the database (UTC) datetime is

```
     '2018-04-03 14:30:00'
```

And the offset is '+01:00'

I would expect the result to be

```
     '2018-04-03 15:30:00'
```

If there an elegant way of doing this? Rather than using grungy arithmetic (which then has to take into account midnight, end of month, end of year etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `FROM_TZ` to create a `TIMSTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, then the conversion is very simple, for example:

```
FROM_TZ({your column}, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'
```

Comment: Thanks. That nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation:

Example of [Converting Time Zones With the AT TIME ZONE Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699):

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1999-12-01 11:00:00',
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York')
     AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' "West Coast Time"
FROM DUAL;

West Coast Time
----------------------------------------------------------
01-DEC-99 08.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

So, applied to your case scenario:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('2018-04-03 14:30:00',
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
     AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' "Greenwich Mean Time"
FROM DUAL;

Greenwich Mean Time
----------------------------------------------------------
03-APR-18 02.30.00.000000 PM GMT
```

You can get the list of available timezones with:

```
SELECT tzname, tzabbrev FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;
```

If you have a table `YOUR_TABLE` with a column `some_timestamp`:

```
create table YOUR_TABLE (
    some_timestamp timestamp
);
/

insert into YOUR_TABLE (
 SOME_TIMESTAMP
) values (
  CAST(TO_DATE('2018-04-03 14:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)
);
```

Then you can run:

```
select
  SOME_TIMESTAMP,
  FROM_TZ(SOME_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' "Greenwich Mean Time",
  FROM_TZ(SOME_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' "London Time"
from YOUR_TABLE;

SOME_TIMESTAMP                  Greenwich Mean Time              London Time
----------------------------------------------------------
03-APR-18 02.30.00.000000 PM    03-APR-18 02.30.00.000000 PM GMT    03-APR-18 03.30.00.000000 PM EUROPE/LONDON
```

And if you are absolutely sure that your server is in UTC, as well as the timestamps introduced, then you can skip that UTC conversion part:

```
select
  SOME_TIMESTAMP,
  SOME_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' "Greenwich Mean Time",
  SOME_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' "London Time"
from YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: UTC is basically the same as GMT, so your code is useless.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit, I'm answering the question as it was defined. It is useless for UTC -> GMT, as are the same thing, but that was not the question. However, I updated the response using London timezone (which change from GMT to BST during the summer) to make that point clear.

Comment: `SOME_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'` does not work  because when you cast a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then Oracle takes the current `SESSIONTIMEZONE` (which can be anything) - not the server time zone.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit, If you read the question, it says:
`The dates in the database are UTC AND the database is set to UTC.`.

And if you read my reply, I said:
`if you are absolutely sure that your server is in UTC...`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: GMT is **not** the same as UTC; the former is the identifier for the winter portion of the UK timezone, which switches to BST in summer time. UTC never does.

Comment: GMT does not, see https://www.worldtimeserver.com/learn/utc-vs-gmt/ or try `tz_offset(TIMESTAMP '2018-07-01 00:00:00 GMT') `

Comment: There is **no time difference** between` UTC` (Coordinated Universal Time) and `GMT` (Greenwich Mean Time). The difference is that UTC is a **standard**, while GMT is a **timezone**. However, Wernfried Domscheit, this doesn't make the code useless, but the example, the code is perfectly fine, is in the official documentation, as I posted, and also, you posted the same code one minute after.

Answer (score -1):

it should be pretty simple::

```
select datetimecolumn + INTERVAL '1' HOUR from mytable
```

hope i understand your requirement correctly.

Comment: How do you handle daylight-saving times?

Comment: Good question , yes my solution do not cater for that.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the equivalent for UTC/BST is

SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1999-12-01 11:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' "London Time" FROM DUAL;

But this returns the same time as UTC. (It doesn't seem to take the +1 hour adjustment to BST into account)

Comment: Yes, because you tested with December which is winter time. Try a date in summer then you will get the offset.